# netgear a6200 error on modprobe ndiswrapper

Tags: networking, ndiswrapper

I'm trying to get a Netgear A6200 wireless card working through USB and I'm getting an error I don't understand. I'm using 14.04 64-bit. I've scoured the net trying to find stuff, and there's duplicate questions on the net. Here's what I've done.

I used bcmwlhigh6.inf as the driver. ndiswrapper would give me driver errors. 
I saw a suggestion that someone use bcmwlhigh5.inf and I've tried that. When I add the driver and then `modprobe ndiswrapper`, I get the following error that I don't understand when I `dmesg | grep ndis`.

> [  583.976609] ndiswrapper (mp_init:211): couldn't initialize device: C0000001
>   [  583.976618] ndiswrapper (pnp_start_device:395): Windows driver couldn't initialize the device (C0000001)
>   [  583.976627] ndiswrapper (mp_halt:254): device ffff880813a3e880 is not initialized - not halting
>   [  583.976630] ndiswrapper: device eth%d removed  [  583.976786] ndiswrapper: probe of 2-1.4:1.0 failed with error -22

To me it seems to like the driver that I used, however it claims there is something wrong w/ the device.

If anyone can offer some suggestions on how to troubleshoot this, I would greatly appreciate it.

mj

Comment: are you using the inf from windows XP? if not, use the XP version instead.

Comment: also, you need to use `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper`; if you don't use `sudo` you will not have the permission to enable the module.

Comment: In the INF file, there is a reference to XP as well as a bunch of others. 
Also, I did sudo the modprobe command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this took me long enough but I figured it out.

For the A6200 I downloaded the drivers directly from the NETGEAR site. There were other sites where people zipped up the necessary files themselves and I was having trouble with them.

1) I used wine to open and install the drivers and it hanged midway through the process. I killed it.

2) I navigated to /home/user/.wine/drive_c/program files (x86)/netgear/a6200/drivers. In there was bcmwlhigh5.inf.

3) I installed the driver via ndisgtk (sudo ndisgtk). I think I had to modprobe ndiswrapper but I can't tell if that helped. At any rate, I saw a blue light blink on the device which promptly went out.

Using iwconfig however showed that the device was detected. Through the network manager  I typed in the security code of my network and I got in.